# Retrofit first call freezes the UI

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit, coroutine

I use Retrofit and TMDB API in my Android app. Retrofit first call freezes the UI. I've tried almost every way but it didn't work. (I've tried to put all the actions in the coroutines) It's keeping freezing on the first call. Thank you so much in advance for your help.
Please check my code:

TmdbService.kt

```
object TmdbService {

fun getClient(): TmdbApi {

    val requestInterceptor = Interceptor {
        val url = it.request()
            .url()
            .newBuilder()
            .addQueryParameter("api_key", API_KEY)
            .build()

        val request = it.request()
            .newBuilder()
            .url(url)
            .build()

        return@Interceptor it.proceed(request)
    }

    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

    val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()

    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .build()
        .create(TmdbApi::class.java)

    }

}
```

TmdbApi.kt

```
interface TmdbApi {
@GET("search/movie")
suspend fun getMovie(
    @Query("query") query: String,
    @Query("page") page: Int
): Response<MovieResult>

@GET("search/tv")
suspend fun getSeries(
    @Query("query") query: String,
    @Query("page") page: Int
): Response<SeriesResult>
}
```

MovieListViewModel.kt

```
class MovieListViewModel : ViewModel() {

//########## TMDB API
private val api: MutableLiveData<TmdbApi> by lazy { MutableLiveData<TmdbApi>() }


//########## Progress MaterialTextView text
private var _progressMTVText = MutableLiveData<String>()
val progressMTVText: LiveData<String>
    get() = _progressMTVText

fun setProgressMTVText(text: String) {
    _progressMTVText.value = text
}


//########## Progress LinearLayout gone
private var _progressLLGone = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val progressLLGone: LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = _progressLLGone

fun isProgressLLGone(gone: Boolean) {
    _progressLLGone.value = gone
}


//########## Get data
fun getData(query: String, adapter: MovieListAdapter) {

    val listData = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = PAGE_SIZE)) {
        MovieDataSource(query, api.value!!)
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    viewModelScope.launch {

        listData.collect {
            adapter.submitData(it)
        }

    }

}


init {

    viewModelScope.launch {
        api.value = TmdbService.getClient()
    }

}

}
```

MovieDataSource.kt

```
class MovieDataSource(private val query: String, private val api: TmdbApi) :
PagingSource<Int, Movie>() {

override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Movie> {

    return try {
        val currentLoadingPageKey = params.key ?: 1
        val responseData = mutableListOf<Movie>()
        responseData.addAll(
            api.getMovie(query, currentLoadingPageKey).body()?.results ?: emptyList()
        )
        
        LoadResult.Page(
            data = responseData,
            prevKey = if (currentLoadingPageKey == 1) null else currentLoadingPageKey - 1,
            nextKey = currentLoadingPageKey.plus(1)
        )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        LoadResult.Error(e)
    }

}

override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Movie>): Int? {
    return state.anchorPosition
}

}
```

MovieListFragment.kt

```
class MovieListFragment : Fragment(), MovieListAdapter.ItemClickListener {

private lateinit var viewModel: MovieListViewModel

private lateinit var binding: FragmentMovieListBinding

private lateinit var adapter: MovieListAdapter

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieListViewModel::class.java)

    binding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_movie_list, container, false)

    binding.let {
        it.viewModel = viewModel
        it.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    }

    observe()

    setRecyclerView()

    viewModel.isProgressLLGone(true)

    return binding.root

}

private fun observe() {

    searchResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {

        if (networkAvailable) {

            if (!it.isNullOrEmpty()) {

                with(viewModel) {
                    setProgressMTVText("${getString(R.string.searching_for)} 
                     \"${searchResult.value}\" ...")
                    isProgressLLGone(false)
                }

                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                    delay(500)
                    viewModel.getData(it, adapter)
                }

            }

        } else R.string.no_internet_connection.showToast(requireContext())

    })

}

private fun setRecyclerView() {

    adapter = MovieListAdapter(this)

    binding.fragmentMovieListMainRV.let {
        it.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        it.adapter = adapter
    }

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {

        adapter.loadStateFlow.collectLatest {

            with(viewModel) {

                when (it.append) {

                    is LoadState.Loading -> {
                        setProgressMTVText("${getString(R.string.searching_for)} 
                       \"${searchResult.value}\" ...")
                        isProgressLLGone(false)
                    }

                    is LoadState.NotLoading -> {
                        setProgressMTVText("")
                        isProgressLLGone(true)
                    }

                    is LoadState.Error -> {
                        setProgressMTVText("")
                        isProgressLLGone(true)
                        if (!networkAvailable) R.string.no_internet_connection.showToast(
                            requireContext()
                        )
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

override fun onItemClick(movie: Movie) {
    startActivity(Intent(context, MovieDetailActivity::class.java).putExtra("movie", movie))
}

}
```

Comment: This doesn't have to do with your freezing, but don't do this: `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch`. That can cause a crash if data arrives while the Fragment is detached. Replace with `lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted`. You've shared a ton of code. Please help us help you and tell us exactly where the first call to the API is made.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The first call is in the MovieListFragment.kt observe() method

Comment: Which calls getData() method in the MovieListViewModel.kt

Comment: I enter the query in the Edittext and when I click enter it gets the data from the API.